# Reading cookies in page on external website displayed in frame

Tags: jquery, cookies, frame

I have a page which is composed by 2 frames like this:

```
<frameset ROWS="50%,50%" border="0" frameborder="0" bordercolor="black">
    <frame id="topFrame" src="" name="top" scrolling="yes" scrollbar="hidden">
    <frame id="downFrame" src="" name="bottom" scrolling="yes" scrollbar="hidden">
</frameset>
```

I want to change the cookies from the page, creating 2 cookies, 1 foreach frame. The content from each frame (src) I'm generating dynamically with javascript. I want to read the cookies foreach website I display with the frame. Can I do that? I'm using jquery with the plugin "jquery.cookie".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, as long as frames "TopFrame" and "DownFrame" are pointing pages to same domain.